# how to set dependecy of RecyclerView Of Android L in Eciplse?

Tags: android

Recently RecyclerView and CardView have been introduced by Android L Version.As per information that I have,The RecyclerView and CardView widgets are part of the v7 Support Libraries. To use these widgets in our project, we have add these Gradle dependencies to our app's module

`dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}`

so IT IS SUPPORTED TO ECLIPSE? if yes then how? or it is supported to Android Studio only? Please help me,if you know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's supported on Eclipse. But you have to add to eclipse manually (res and java code). You can download source from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-5.0.2_r1/v7/).